# Iterate text file containing characters with different byte lengths

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I'm opening a text dump, and trying to parse the contents out.  Right now I'm just trying to ID different parts of the file (headers, labels, etc) to work from later.  I'm IDing lines based on the first character.  Some lines begin with `¯` (macron), some with `=`.

```
macron = '\xc2\xaf'
equalSign = '='
nullLines = 0

f = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in f:
    tempList = line.rsplit()
    if len(tempList) > 0:
        switchStr = tempList[0]
    else:
        print("tempList !> 0")
        nullLines = nullLines + 1
    if switchStr[0:2] == macron:
        print("macron")
    elif switchStr[0] == equalSign:
        print('equals')
    else:
        print switchStr
print(nullLines)
f.close()
```

This code works, but I'm confused.  `rsplit()` splits whitespace.  If I have a line such as `===================` in the file, `tempList` is length = 1 and `switchStr = '==================='`.  The same is true with the macron.

OK, so I tried to find the first character in each string with `switchStr[0]', but for macron, it didn't work, I needed the first "two" (but obviously just one), eg`switchStr[0:2].  It does work for equals.  This interpreter output illustrates the thing I don't understand:

```
>>> line = '¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯'
>>> line
'\xc2\xaf\xc2\xaf\xc2\xaf\xc2\xaf\xc2\xaf\xc2\xaf\xc2\xaf\xc2\xaf\xc2\xaf\xc2\xaf'
>>> print line
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
>>> line = '=========='
>>> line
'=========='
>>> print line
==========
>>>
```

So, some "characters" need 2 bytes, and some just one, but how can I programmatically figure out the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

[Stop dealing with bytes.](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

```
with io.open(sys.argv[1], encoding='utf-8') as f:
  line = f.readline()
  print line[0]
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what this does or why it addresses the problem, could you add a little more detail?

Comment: `>>> len('¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯')`
`20`
`>>> len(u'¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯')`
`10`
`>>> print u'¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯'[0]`
`¯`